Nicer \sqrt with urw-garamond
The \sqrt in the urw-garamond (mathdesign) package becomes upright at very little, like in the example image.

I don't suppose this behaviour can be changed? Is it possible to replace the \sqrt command from another package which fits well with this font?
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{\frac{2}{5a_{0}}}
\]

\end{document}


Please can you add your minimal compilable tex code? With XeLaTeX there is no problem (for example)\documentclass[12pt]{article} \usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math} \setmainfont{EB Garamond}  \setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf} \begin{document} \[E=\sqrt{\frac{2}{5a_0}}\] \end{document} I have not installed the urw-garamond package fonts.

Using Unicode Math, (loaded font: Garamond-Math.otf), there is no problem. The formula $$ \sqrt{2\over5a_0} $$ has slanted root symbol. I recommend: don't use old non-Unicode engines, fonts etc. today.

Thanks for the responses. I actually meant the urw-garamond by mathdesign package. Personally, it looks more pleasing to me than garamond-math.otf with XeLaTeX. Is there a way to replace the sqrt?

You might do like ebgaramond-maths which borrows large symbols from Computer Modern.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}

\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}{%
  <-7.5> cmex7
  <7.5-8.5> cmex8
  <8.5-9.5> cmex9
  <9.5-> cmex10
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathRadical{\sqrtsign}{CMsymbols}{"70}{CMlargesymbols}{"70}

\begin{document}

\[
\sqrt{4}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}
+\sqrt{\frac{2}{5\smash[b]{a_{0}}}}
+\sqrt{\frac{2}{5a_{0}}}
\]

\end{document}

In the third radical I show how to reduce the size of the radical by “smashing” the depth of the subscript.

For completeness, the same input but with \usepackage{ebgaramond-maths} replacing \usepackage[urw-garamond}{mathdesign}.


Thanks! That worked magic! May I ask a bit about the code?  It seems CM indicates computer modern. What about the codes for other fonts? Can we borrow symbols from any of them?  Sorry for the bother!

@Kointoss cmex is the family name for Computer Modern Extension Symbols, the CM prefixes I used are actually arbitrary. There are several questions on the site about importing symbols.
